# How to compute cyclomatic complexity for empty whiles and if + breaks?

Tags: conditions, cyclomatic-complexity

This is closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950471/cyclomatic-complexity-draw-control-flow-graph-for-this-java-statement/35950716?noredirect=1#comment85161854_35950716) which asks about the complexity of the following:

```
while (x > level)
    x = x – 1;
x = 0
```

Using the graph method it has a Complexity = 2. [Fred Swartz](http://www.leepoint.net/principles_and_practices/complexity/complexity-java-method.html) indicates a more faster way of computing complexity for Java/C# based on actual instructions from these languages:

```
- Start with a count of one for the method.
- Add one for each of the following flow-related elements that are found in the method.
    Returns - Each return that isn't the last statement of a method.
    Selection - if, else, case, default.
    Loops - for, while, do-while, break, and continue.
    Operators - &&, ||, ?, and :
    Exceptions - catch, finally, throw, or throws clause.
```

However, `nonconvergent` asks about how `if .. break` should be treated. So, I am thinking rewriting above code like this:

```
while (true)
{
    if (x > level) 
        break;

    x = x – 1;
}
x = 0
```

While this is equivalent to the initial algorithm, I would theoretically add a complexity of 2 (`if` + `break`).

My feeling is that `if ... break` should count as 1 and empty `while`s should not count at all.

**Question:** How to compute cyclomatic complexity for empty whiles and if + breaks?

Comment: One indication why your rewrite is bad: You introduced a big fat bug. And seven lines of code where two work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first say that you should generally favor not using infinite loops with an internal break. They are much harder to follow for readers of your code and likely to cause maintenance problems.

That said, a `while(true)` is not an "empty while." From the point of view of cyclomatic complexity we want to know how often the code branches. There's still a branch at the end of the loop that goes back to the beginning. You've added yet another branch with the `if` statement. So I would say that you should count it as additional complexity. In fact, I'm tempted to count your `if...break` as 2 since there's the branch for the `if` and the additional branch for the `break`.

Even if you don't agree with my assessment of the cyclomatic complexity, surely you can see that reading the code is harder with the `if...break`. In the original code, I can clearly see that we're decrementing `x` until it's equal to `level`. In the second code snippet, I have to think a lot harder to see that.

Furthermore `break` is confusing in C-based languages. It's most common use is in `switch` statements, where it's fairly easy to understand, since that's where most people first learn about it. Once you put it inside nested control structures, it becomes much more confusing. Does it break out of only the one it's in, like with a `switch` statement? Well that doesn't make sense here because it's the last line of an `if`. You could just not put it there and you'd be out of the `if` at the closing brace. So it must break out of the control structure outside of that. But what if that's inside another control structure? Does it break out of that too? If not, why not? And why when it's used with a `switch` does it not also break out of the enclosing control structure? As such, I tend to avoid using `break` anywhere other than `switch` statements.

Comment: I rarely use `while(true)` and here I used it just as an example. So, the second form will significantly increase the complexity. I agree with `break` usage and I rarely use it.

Comment: I recommend for(;;) for loops with an exit condition inside the loop. That’s the idiomatic way to write it.

Comment: And for(;;) with internal break or continue is exactly what you want if you don’t know whether to break or continue at the start of the loop.